# Storing individual doubles from a packed double vector using Intel AVX

Tags: x86, x86-64, sse, avx

I'm writing code using the C intrinsics for Intel's AVX instructions. If I have a packed double vector (a `__m256d`), what would be the most efficient way (i.e. the least number of operations) to store each of them to a different place in memory (i.e. I need to fan them out to different locations such that they are no longer packed)? Pseudocode:

```
__m256d *src;
double *dst;
int dst_dist;
dst[0] = src[0];
dst[dst_dist] = src[1];
dst[2 * dst_dist] = src[2];
dst[3 * dst_dist] = src[3];
```

Using SSE, I could do this with `__m128` types using the `_mm_storel_pi` and `_mm_storeh_pi` intrinsics. I've not been able to find anything similar for AVX that allows me to store the individual 64-bit pieces to memory. Does one exist?

Comment: I think you wanted to use `__m256d`. `__m256` is 8 floats.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. I missed it because I don't use `__m256d`; I'm actually using floats. The doubles that I want to extract and store are actually complex numbers (two floats, or the size of one double).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a couple of extract instrinsics: (warning: untested)

```
 __m256d src = ...  //  data

__m128d a = _mm256_extractf128_pd(src, 0);
__m128d b = _mm256_extractf128_pd(src, 1);

_mm_storel_pd(dst + 0*dst_dist, a);
_mm_storeh_pd(dst + 1*dst_dist, a);
_mm_storel_pd(dst + 2*dst_dist, b);
_mm_storeh_pd(dst + 3*dst_dist, b);
```

What you want is the gather/scatter instructions in AVX2... But that's still a few years down the road.

Comment: For those like me that stumbled upon this a decade later `_mm256_stream_pd` is probably what you want instead (see [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=3171,6943,4894,5397,6138,833,7195,7158,7188,6888,6888&text=_mm256_stream_pd) ).