# Non-temporal stores of portions of a packed double vector using SSE/AVX

Tags: caching, x86, x86-64, sse, avx

This piggybacks on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440793/storing-individual-doubles-from-a-packed-double-vector-using-intel-avx) that I had regarding fanning out the individual elements of an `__m256d` vector to different memory locations (a scatter operation). My code stores a lot of data to memory that isn't again accessed for a "long time." I would like to reduce the amount of cache pollution generated by all of these stores by using the non-temporal hint instructions. However, I can't come up with a good way to do this. Here's a summary of what my code looks like now:

```
__m256d src = ...  //  data
double *dst;
int dst_dist;

__m128d a = _mm256_extractf128_pd(src, 0);
__m128d b = _mm256_extractf128_pd(src, 1);

_mm_storel_pd(dst + 0*dst_dist, a);
_mm_storeh_pd(dst + 1*dst_dist, a);
_mm_storel_pd(dst + 2*dst_dist, b);
_mm_storeh_pd(dst + 3*dst_dist, b);
```

I would like to perform the 64-bit stores using the non-temporal hint, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly from an XMM register. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good reason to avoid using partial register stores with the non-temporal hint. If you try to scatter many small pieces of data to completely unrelated memory locations, CPU's write combining buffers overflow and you get just a usual write through the caches (probably with additional performance cost).

The correct way to use write combining (non-temporal hint) is to fill up the entire cache line. So it is usual to combine data pieces to a complete register, then write it at once with MOVNTDQ.

Comment: Good thought. Your and Stephen's answers show that I need to rethink the structure of my algorithm. I'm probably writing too many scattered pieces at once (I have two modes, one where I write 8 64-bit values out at a time and another where I write 16).

Answer (score 2):

You can store portions of an SSE vector with a non-temporal hint using the `MASKMOVDQU` instruction.  The semantics don't map precisely onto your example, but it can be made to work.  However, this instruction should generally only be used to avoid branching (even then, it is usually be better to use a select and a normal store).  It's also simply a little cumbersome to use, since the address to which to store is implicit in the instruction.

The operation that you're performing looks rather a lot like a piece of a matrix transpose (or 90 degree image rotation).  Do you eventually store other data to the adjacent addresses?  Is there some way you can modify your algorithm to batch up those stores and write complete vectors instead (possibly even by using contiguous writes to a small cacheable scratch buffer and doing some write-combining in software)?

Comment: A matrix-transpose-like function is part of the operation I'm implementing. I do eventually store data to the adjacent addresses. I believe the overall algorithm is memory-access-time limited right now, so I've structured it to minimize the amount of stores (all of the computation is done in the SSE/AVX registers, nothing on the stack). I've thought about doing what you've proposed, but I haven't coded it up to see how it compares. One complicating factor is that I can't guarantee 128-bit alignment on all of my stores, which is why I've been using MOVHPD/MOVLPD to write 64 bits at a time.